# React, Typescript, Redux - <Link to=URL> causes component to dissapear

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

### **Background**

App is created via `npx create-react-app rrts --typescript`. Which sets up React, Redux, Typescript.

### **Visual Representation Of The Problem**

(`Content` is the component with sentences)
https://gyazo.com/bb14af9cb3f0870107ec775a328e60c0

### **Description of Problem**

When the Logo is clicked (which has `<Link to="\">)` is clicked, the component (called `Content`) that is supposed to show up dissapears. `Content` renders when the page loads, but it disappears if the logo is clicked.

### **What I have tried**

1. I re-built my app with
   https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-forest-0ilef?file=/src/reducers/index.tsx

   The sandbox works perfectly.  None of the components are
   disappearing when `<Link to=url/>` is clicked. Concluding that **how
   I set up the code is not the issue**. In my actual project, I
   believe the issue is in  **import history** and **typescript** because `<Router history={history}>` works in non-typescript react projects.

   Particulary here in **history.tsx**

   ```
   import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
   export default createBrowserHistory();
   ```

   I installed it via `npm -i history --save.` [Docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/issues/681). Not
   installing **history** would give me a **history** module not found
   on my imports.

**Picture of console.log(history) being used in App.tsx:**

[image: console.log(history) in App.tsx]

**My dependencies:**

```
       "@types/jest": "^24.9.1",
        "@types/node": "^12.12.50",
        "@types/react": "^16.9.42",
        "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.8",
        "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.5",
        "cloudinary-react": "^1.6.2",
        "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.9",
        "axios": "^0.19.2",
        "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
        "redux": "^4.0.5",
        "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
        "history": "^5.0.0",
        "react": "^16.13.1",
        "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
        "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
        "typescript": "^3.7.5"


  [1]: https://www.npmjs.com/package/history
```

2. Came across [history/createBrowserHistory broken for TS on latest release (v4.9.0)](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/issues/681)
   Tried the suggestion of renaming **history.tsx to browserhistory.tsx**. **Did not work.**

What the poster said:

In history.ts,

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history' // --> seems like a conflict
export default createBrowserHistory()
so I renamed my file to browserhistory.ts and it worked fine again.

In browserhistory.ts,

import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history' // --> no more conflict occurs
export default createBrowserHistory()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved in:
https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/issues/822

npm install history 5.0.0 is bugged.  and history,push() will somehow make your component dissapear.

Installing npm install history@4.10.1 solved the issue.